# Excel Array Filter with Date Range

Tags: arrays, excel, date, excel-formula, filtering

My formula does not work when I try to filter using a date range:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(HistoricTrades,SEQUENCE(ROWS(HistoricTrades)),
XMATCH(BH1:CE1,HistoricTrades[#Headers])),
(HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2*(HistoricTrades[Date]>=BC2)))
```

The HistoricTrades is just a table with all the detail.  My array can filter is I just use one date parameter but not a date range.  It just returns #VALUE.  The headers references are in columns BH!:CE1 and are present in the worksheet with the table and represent the headers of the data in the table.

Does anyone know who a dynamic array with a date range filter an work?  It would be greatly appreciated!  Thank!

I expected to see trades that were done for the date range in question.  For example trades with dates between 6/30/2022 and 7/31/2022.  My filter works for greater than or equal to a single date, but when I put in either of these for a date range it errors out and I get #VALUE:

```
(HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2*(HistoricTrades[Date]>=BC2)))
```

or

```
(BC2<=HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2)
```

Comment: I think there is a typo.

Comment: (BC2<=HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2)  is not valid expression. First one is missing parentheses around HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2, should be ((HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2)*(HistoricTrades[Date]>=BC2))

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

You can try this filter...

```
=FILTER(INDEX(HistoricTrades,SEQUENCE(ROWS(HistoricTrades)),XMATCH(BH1:CE1,HistoricTrades[#Headers])),
(HistoricTrades[Date]>=BC2)*(HistoricTrades[Date]<=BB2))
```

The correct way to check if a date falls within a range is by using two separate logical operators instead of multiplication.

Comment: Thanks very much!  It works like a charm.  I was close but had too many parathesis was baffled!  Thanks again!  Best, Tom